# ui5 sap.m.PDFViewer - embedded toolbar

Tags: javascript, download, sapui5

I stream a PDF file from the ERP backend and display it in the sap.m.PDFViewer control. I have set showDownloadButton property value to "false". The download button has disappeared in the popup footer.

Unfortunately there is another download button in the integrated toolbar.

[Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9F4D.jpg)

Can someone give me a hint on how to remove this button?

In fact, all I need is the rotate button.

Answer (score 1):

The “integrated” download button in the screenshot is part of the (native) program that is used to display the PDF - part of the browser or a browser plugin. You can’t control that from the server side (or using JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

The sap.m.PDFViewer has a property "showDownloadButton". If you set it to false, the download button should be suppressed.